# How to keep user in website at the background via services?

Tags: android

I'm sorry for my english. I want to open website and keep user always online in website at background on android phone. How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by keeping him online?

Comment: yesli polzovatel otkrivaet etot prilojeniya toqda on budet online v sayte (v facebooke ili druqie)

Comment: I don;t speak that language, sorry. Please use English only on this forum.

Comment: if user opens app then he'll online in website which is defined in app

Comment: It is not the app, which decides if the user is online, but the website. Do you know how exactly it decides? *Probably* you only need to keep your app running, for example - using ForegroundService, but nobody knows how exectly each web site decides if the user is online